# How to add the auto mute function to this javascript code that allows it to be muted automatically when it loads?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

So this code loads a video in my android app. However, I want to be able to mute/unmute the video automatically when it's loaded.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>id='showtv'; id_width=600; id_height=300; 
id_p=2;</script><script type='text/javascript' 
src='http://cdn.crichd.info/channel.js'></script>
```

Is there any extra code I could had to have the auto mute feature? If so, where must it be placed?

Comment: Could you not find the element and change it's volume attribute?

Comment: No because I've disabled touch interactions in the app for that specific video.

Comment: That shouldn't prevent JS from accessing the attribute?

Comment: No it won't....